# Fullcalendar not rendering days

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have a strange problem with Fullcalendar. The calendar is not fully rendered. Only the header is rendered initially and I have to click on any header button to make the calendar render days and events.

HTML + Razor:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.User, @Model.UsersDropdown, new { id = "calendar_uid", @class = "form-control" })
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div id="calendar" data-lang="@Request.UserLanguages[0]"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    buttonIcons: {
        prev: 'left-single-arrow',
        next: 'right-single-arrow',
        prevYear: 'left-double-arrow',
        nextYear: 'right-double-arrow'
    },
    events: {
        url: SITE_ROOT + '/Calendar/Feed',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            uid: $('#calendar_uid').val()
        }
    },


});

$("#calendar_uid").change(function () {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEventSource', SITE_ROOT + '/Calendar/Feed');
    var newSource = {
        url: SITE_ROOT + '/Calendar/Feed',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            uid: this.value
        }
    };
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', newSource);

});
```

To make things stranger if I call `$("#calendar").fullCalendar('render');` from firebug console the calender is fully rendered. However if I call it after initialization from my scripts nothing happens. I took a look in the network tab of Firebug as well. No request is sent to the server when the calender is rendered for the first time. The request is sent when I click any of the header buttons. Afterwards everything works fine.

I also tried to copy [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arshaw/3E8nk/) fiddle and see if it works locally. I still have the same problem. I need to click any button to make the calendar render completely.

Last but not least my script includes(at the bottom of my page):

```
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/jquery.hideseek.js"></script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>


<script>
    moment().format();
</script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/app_calendar.js"></script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/app_contacts.js"></script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/app_newPhone.js"></script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/app_newEmail.js"></script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/app_newAppointment.js"></script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/app_newActivity.js"></script>
<script src="/C5.WebApp/Scripts/application.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you try setting defaultView?

Comment: @RichardHermanson Yes same results

Comment: Just an idea, what happens if you add one of the views to the header (as a button)? It will be hard to help without a jsfiddle or something

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340362/jquery-fullcalendar-not-rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the docs again and again I found the [this](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/)

> Notice that this example calls render whenever any tab is shown, not just the tab that the calendar is within. This is okay, because **FullCalendar is smart enough to only render calendars that are visible to the user.**

The problem is my calendar was hidden initially and I expected it to be rendered when I remove the `hidden` class via javascript.